# Click events in for HTML and SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have some elements in the DOM as below

```
<div id="container">

   <div id="div_container">
     <div id="Scroller"/>
   </div>

   <svg id="svg_container">
   </svg>

</div>
```

[image: DOM View]

And i handled click event for the parent div ("container"), when i click the container, evt.target.id that i am getting is "Scroller". But the SVG element is appended at last, so when i click the target should be SVG right? But i am getting the DIV ("Scroller") as target. Is anything, that i am doing wrong?

What to do if the target element should be SVG?

Here is my Sample
[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/tq3hrbcm/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using jquery not just use the element it gives you then use .find() or .children() to select the svg

Comment: Maybe since the Scroller div is absolute position, it's overlapping the svg image? Just might be an option

Comment: You can't get click events from a bare svg container. There has to be somethin rendered in it to click on.

Comment: @RobertLongson, there is an Rect inside the svg

Comment: please create a [mcve] then.

Comment: @Robert, i have attached sample for your reference in my question

Comment: You have to set your svg's position to relative : https://jsfiddle.net/tq3hrbcm/2/